# counting number of lines words and characters without using wc command

Tags: centos, files, find

I have made programs using `wc` commands, but I want to know how to count the number of lines, words, and characters without using `wc` in a file using a shell script.

Comment: _characters_ (like  in `wc -m`) or _bytes_ (like in `wc -c` or the 3rd field in `wc`'s output)?

Comment: Count lines with `grep -c $` filename

Comment: Words could be counted with `sed 's/[[:space:]]/\n/g' filename | grep -c .`

Comment: I want to count characters (like in wc -m)

Answer (score 3):

To count the number of bytes (like `wc -c`)

```
< file LC_ALL=C tr -c '\n' '[\n*]' | grep -c '^'
```

To count the number of newline characters (like `wc -l`):

```
< file LC_ALL=C tr -cd '\n' | grep -c '^'
```

For words (like `wc -w`), assuming a POSIX compliant `tr` like FreeBSD's (not GNU's) and assuming the file doesn't contain illegal byte sequences:

```
< file tr -cs '[:space:]' '[x*]' | tr -cs x '[\n*]' | grep -c x
```

For characters (like `wc -m`), same restrictions:

```
< file tr -c '\n' '[\n*]' | grep -c '^'
```

On the output of:

```
printf '\0foo\u2006and \r\fbar\nbaz'
```

They give respectively 20, 1, 4, 18, like `wc` on a FreeBSD system in a en_GB.UTF-8 locale.